# Determining the type of a function in Functional Programming

Tags: types, definition

The following equations are written in Miranda Syntax, but due to the similarities between Miranda and Haskell I expect Haskell programmers should understand it!

If you define the following functions:

```
rc v g i = g (v:i)
rn x = x
rh g = hd (g [])


f [] y = y 
f (x:xs) y = f xs (rc x y)

g [] y = y
g (x:xs) y = g xs (x:y)
```

How do you work out the type of the functions?  I think I understand how to work it out for f,g and rn but I'm confused about the partial application part.

**rn is going to be * -> *** (*or anything -> anything, I think it's a -> a in Haskell?*)

For f and g, are the function types both **[*] -> * -> ***?

I'm unsure how to approach finding the types for rc and rh though.  In rc, g is being partially applied to the variable i - so I'm guessing that this constrains the type of i to be [*].  What order are rc and g applied in the definition of rc?  Is g applied to i, and then the resulting function used as the argument for rc?  Or does rc take 3 separate parameters of v,g and i?  I'm really confused.. any help would be appreciated!  Thanks guys.

Sorry forgot to add that hd is the standard head function for a list and is defined as:

```
hd :: [*] -> *
hd (a:x) = a
hd [] = error "hd []"
```

Comment: No, i'm preparing for exams right now and it's an old exam question for a Miranda exam.

Comment: What is the type of the `hd` function?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that definition - i've added it to the question now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type is inferred from what is already known of types and how expressions are used in the definition.

Let's begin at the top,

```
rc v g i = g (v : i)
```

so `rc :: a -> b -> c -> d` and we must see what can be found out about `a, b, c` and `d`. On the right hand side, there appears `(v : i)`, so with `v :: a`, we see that `i :: [a]`, `c = [a]`. Then `g` is applied to `v : i`, so `g :: [a] -> d`, altogether,

```
rc :: a -> ([a] -> d) -> [a] -> d
```

`rn x = x` means that there's no constraint on the argument type of `rn` and its return type is the same, `rn :: a -> a`.

```
rh g = hd (g [])
```

Since `rh`'s argument `g` is applied to an empty list on the RHS, it must have type `[a] -> b`, possibly more information about `a` or `b` follows. Indeed, `g []` is the argument of `hd` on the RHS, so `g [] :: [c]` and `g :: [a] -> [c]`, hence

```
rh :: ([a] -> [c]) -> c
```

Next

```
f [] y = y 
f (x:xs) y = f xs (rc x y)
```

The first argument is a list, and if that is empty, the result is the second argument, so `f :: [a] -> b -> b` follows from the first equation. Now, in the second equation, on the RHS, the second argument to `f` is `rc x y`, hence `rc x y` must have the same type as `y`, we called that `b`. But

```
rc :: a -> ([a] -> d) -> [a] -> d
```

, so `b = [a] -> d`. Hence

```
f :: [a] -> ([a] -> d) -> [a] -> d
```

Finally

```
g [] y = y
g (x:xs) y = g xs (x:y)
```

from the first equation we deduce `g :: [a] -> b -> b`. From the second, we deduce `b = [a]`, since we take the head of `g`'s first argument and cons it to the second, thus

```
g :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel!  With the first equation, rc, we apply g to i which we have identified as type [a] - but how do we know the output of the function is type d?  Isn't that just the only the output of rc, and not necessarily also the output of g?

Comment: We don't know anything about the type of `g`'s result from the definition of `rc`, so whatever is the result type of the passed argument `g` is the result type of `rc` in that call. For types that can be anything, we use a type variable, whether we call it `d` or `simon` is immaterial. Here we must not call it `a`, because that is already used for another type (but is is legal to pass a `g1 :: [b] -> b`, the type `d` may be equal to `a`, but it need not, hence it gets a different denotation). I left it `d` because that's what was the result type in the first approximation to `rc`'s type.

Comment: If the result of rc is simply another g function, why is the output of rc not given as [a] -> d?  Making the whole thing:
    rc :: a -> ([a] -> d) -> [a] -> ([a] -> d)

Comment: The result of `rc` is not another `g` function, it's _the result of applying_ `g` _to_ `(v:i)`, so `rc`'s result type is `g`'s result type.

Comment: ahhh!  Got it!  Thanks for being so patient!

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to use the haskell syntax to write types.

```
rc v g i = g (v:i)
```

Here `rc` takes three parameters, so its type will be something like `a -> b -> c -> d`.
`v:i` must be a list of elements of the same type as `v` and `i`, so `v :: a` and `i :: [a]`.
`g` is applied to that list, so that `g :: [a] -> d`.
If you put all together, you get `rc :: a -> ([a] -> d) -> [a] -> d`.

As you already figured out `rn :: a -> a`, because it is simply the identity.

I have no idea about the type of the `hd` function you use in `rh`, so I'll skip that.

```
f [] y = y 
f (x:xs) y = f xs (rc x y)
```

Here `f` takes two parameters, so its type will be something like `a -> b -> c`.
From the first case we can deduce that `b == c`, since we return `y`, and that the first argument is a list.
For now we know that `f :: [a'] -> b -> b`.
In the second case notice how `x` and `y` are given in input to `rc`: `y` must be a function `[a'] -> d`, and `rc x y :: a' -> d` (that must be also the type of `y`, since it is passed as it second argument of `f`).
Finally, we can say that `f :: [a'] -> ([a'] -> d) -> ([a'] -> d)`. Since `->` is right-associative, this is equivalent to `[a'] -> ([a'] -> d) -> [a'] -> d`.

You can reason in the same manner for the remaining ones.

Comment: `hd` is from the Miranda standard library. It's equivalent to `head` in Haskell, so its type is `[a] -> a`.

Comment: Thanks Riccardo!  Could you take a look at the question I've asked Daniel as it also applies to your answer - thanks!

Comment: Pleasure. I'm sorry, I arrived late. He already explained you :)